Electron Forge with Vue 3 integration doesn't work
i want develop an Electron app integrated with Vue 3 using electron forge.
I've followed this official documentation
Electron Vue integration .
But when i run the command
npm start

the application doesn't start!
The output in the terminal is:
john@Macbook-Jon arrayforge % npm start

   > arrayforge@1.0.0 start
   > electron-forge start

   ✔ Checking your system
   ✔ Locating application
   ✔ Loading configuration
   ✔ Preparing native dependencies [0.2s]
   ✔ Running generateAssets hook

   
   ✔ [plugin-vite] Launching dev servers for renderer process code [0.1s]
   ⠹ [plugin-vite] Compiling main process code
john@Macbook-JON arrayforge %  

Any ideas?

Don't break the vite.render.config.j/ts. Just add vue() into prop array plugin:[].
